# Plotly R: can't add segment to a ordered bar plot

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Basically, I have this **dataframe**:

```
# dataframe
df2 = data.frame(value = c(9, 2, 7, 5, 6),
                 key = c('ar', 'or', 'br', 'gt', 'ko'))
```

And this is the plot I **need**. I'm using `reorder`, because I know it is a good way to order the bars correctly.

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(reorder(key, -value), value), fill = 'grey') + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 4)
```

[CORRECT PLOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aTlN.png)

---

I'm trying to do this in `plotly`, but everytime I use `reorder`, it doesn't work properly.

Also, I would like the `segment` to start in the extreme **left side** of the first bar and end in the extreme **right side** of the last bar.

```
# using reorder to order the bars doesn't work!
df2 %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~reorder(key, -value), # <- here
          y = ~value,
          color = I('grey'),
          type = 'bar') %>% 
  add_segments(x = 'ar', xend = 'or',
               y = 4, yend = 4, 
               color = I('black'))
```

[WRONG PLOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOOJC.png)

Any tips here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that adding the segments breaks the order of your bars. However, adapting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40149759/12993861) to your example you could achieve your desired result by manually setting the order of the x axis via `layout`:

```r
library(plotly)

xform <- list(categoryorder = "array",
              categoryarray = levels(reorder(df2$key, -df2$value)))

df2 %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~key,
          y = ~value,
          color = I('grey'),
          type = 'bar') %>% 
  add_segments(x = 'ar', xend = 'or',
               y = 4, yend = 4, 
               color = I('black')) %>%
  layout(xaxis = xform)
```

[image]

To fix your second issue: Adapting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68936805/bar-chart-and-vertical-line-with-discrete-axis-in-plotly/68938332#68938332) you could switch to a continuous scale by converting your `key` variable to a numeric and setting the axis labels via `layout`:

```r
df2 %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~ as.numeric(reorder(key, -value)),
    y = ~value,
    color = I("grey"),
    type = "bar"
  ) %>%
  add_segments(
    x = .6, xend = 5.4,
    y = 4, yend = 4,
    color = I("black")
  ) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      ticktext = levels(reorder(df2$key, -df2$value)),
      tickvals = seq_along(df2$key),
      tickmode = "array",
      range = c(0.5, 5.5)
    )
  )
```

[image]